# ASP.NET MVC - Is there a way to return 2 PartialViews?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to return 2 PartialViews in my ActionResult instead of one?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve Sanderson blogged about using partial requests in ASP.NET MVC, it may not quite be what you are looking for but his solution allows you to attach partial views to the ViewData in a controller action which is then used on the view with the help of an extension method.

It may give you ideas on how to solve your problem: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/10/14/partial-requests-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Thanks argibson! It's what I need! :-)